# Broken fonts in Emacs over SSH

Tags: ssh, emacs

I'm having a problem with Emacs when I SSH from my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop to another Linux machine.  FWIW, I believe the remote machine is using SUSE Enterprise Server 10 SP2, which is possibly quite old.  I connect using `ssh -X <server>`.  When I run Emacs, I get the error messages

```
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-courier-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-*--*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
```

and Emacs is full of boxes instead of text characters, as shown below.

[image]

I've tried flushing my local font cache with `sudo fc-cache -f -v` but that didn't help.  Ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I found that this solved my emacs problem

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1896584

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.